# How to decide which type (class/struct) is correct to store JSON data

Tags: json, swift

As we know, Swift prefers value types than reference types. I have a basic question because I am going to create a new application which interacts with a server. How to decide which type suits better to store JSON data? What do we need to keep in mind while storing JSON data in reference type or value type and how to decide which type suites better?

It will be great if anyone explain with an example.

Answer (score 3):

Always prefer structs as the object type *par excellence* unless you have a reason to use classes. But you might very well have a reason to use classes. If you parse your data into an overall type and that type is now your app's model data, it will probably need to be a class so that you can pass it around conveniently by reference. Even more telling is whether you ever need to *mutate* the object; if you add mutating methods to a struct, you can very quickly come to wish it were a class.

Comment: Some are born classes, some achieve classness, and some have classness thrust upon them. :)

Answer (score 0):

For this concept of struct and class will help.

Use **Struct** when you just want to store data **not to assign value/identity** to its object.

Use **Class** when you want to **assign and change the value/identity** of the object.

**Unless until you really know that you need to change objects identity use** **Struct**

To read into detail please have a look into this.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/choosing_between_structures_and_classes

Comment: What is the meaning of Change Objects Identity? Can you explain by example?